# How would I make this only display one result and add a randomize button?

Tags: javascript, html, json

so I have this code that displays all the objects that fit a variable in a JSON file using Jput.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#tbody").jPut({
    ajax_url:"valid_data.json",
    prepend:true, 
    name:"tbody_template",
});

});
</script>  

<table jput="t_template">
 <tbody jput="tbody_template">
     <tr>
         <td>{{First Name}}</td>
         <td>{{Middle Name}}</td>
         <td>{{Last Name}}</td>
         <td>{{Nationality}}</td>
         <td>{{Birthplace}}</td>
         <td>{{Age}}</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<table>
 <tbody id="tbody">
 </tbody>
</table>

<script src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jput.min.js"></script>
```

Code works fine, (can be seen in action at http://fooda.website/test2.html) but i need a button that when clicked picks a random array and displays only that arrays result.

Javascript knowledge is minimal so not sure how to go about it. Had some previous code that was linked to a CSV file before I was advised to convert to JSON, but i'm lost as to how to implement it in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain about options of `.jPut()`, though one option would be to set all `tr` elements `style` to `display:none`, then select random `tr` from `table` and set that `tr` to `display:block`.

According to linked documentation, `done` option is called when `JSON` is returned.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://fooda.website/jput.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var tr, button = $("button");
      $("#tbody").jPut({
        ajax_url: "http://fooda.website/valid_data.json",
        prepend: true,
        name: "tbody_template",
        done: function(e) {
          tr = $("table #tbody tr").hide();
          button.removeAttr("disabled")
        }
      });

      button.click(function() {
        tr.hide();
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * tr.length);
        tr.eq(rand).show()
      });
    });
  </script>
  <button disabled>click</button>
  <table jput="t_template" style="display: none;">
    <tbody jput="tbody_template" style="display: none;">
      <tr>
        <td>{{First Name}}</td>
        <td>{{Middle Name}}</td>
        <td>{{Last Name}}</td>
        <td>{{Nationality}}</td>
        <td>{{Birthplace}}</td>
        <td>{{Age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody id="tbody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/NURw4djMh9Jp23v3bINP?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the response @guest271314 , however this didn't work... when button is clicked, nothing is displayed. could be interfering with jput? 
Some documentation can be found here if it helps: https://github.com/shabeer-ali-m/jPut